# Add line to .xml using pugixml and C++

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, pugixml

I have an XML document that I need to write to using pugixml and Cpp. Part of my XML document looks like this:

```
line 4                   <people>
line 5                   <guys>
line 6                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 7                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 8                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 9                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 10                  <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 11                  </guys>
line 12                   <guys>
line 13                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 14                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 15                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 16                   <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 17                  <dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5" />
line 18                  </guys>
                         </people>
```

How would I add another (dude name="man" delay="1" life="0.75" score="5") line after line 13, moving all the other lines down one in my .xml file?

I am trying....

```
//get xml object
  pugi::xml_document doc;
//load xml file
  doc.load_file(pathToFile.c_str);
//edit file
  doc.child("people").child("guys").append_copy(doc.child("people").child("guys").child("dude"));
//save file
doc.save_file(pathToFile.c_str);
```

But it doesn't appear to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear how [the documentation](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html) has let you down.  Did you notice the table of contents on the right?

Comment: Yeah I have been reading through it but still not sure how I could get it to work with my situation. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) it becomes much easier and readable without all that `child()` function calls.

To insert in the first row moving all other lines bellow use `prepend_copy` function.

This works here with your example xml:

```
pugi::xml_document doc;

//load xml file
doc.load_file(pathToFile);

pugi::xpath_node nodeToInsert;
pugi::xpath_node nodeParent;

try
{
    nodeToInsert = doc.select_single_node("/people/guys[2]/dude[1]");
    nodeParent = doc.select_single_node("/people/guys[2]");
}

catch (const pugi::xpath_exception& e)
{
    cerr << "error " << e.what() << endl;
    return -1;
}

nodeParent.node().prepend_copy(nodeToInsert.node()); // insert at the first row

//save file
std::cout << "Saving result: " << doc.save_file("output.xml") << std::endl;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much appreciated